# Which parties are in the current Romanian government (coalition)?

Tags: parties, government, romania, coalition

Confusingly enough, Romania has two liberal parties, one called [PNL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Liberal_Party_(Romania)) (National Liberal) which supported the [re-election of] the current president Klaus Iohannis, and another called [ALDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alliance_of_Liberals_and_Democrats_(Romania)) (Democrat Liberal). The latter Democrat Liberal party was the junior partner of the coalition with the Social Democrats (PSD) until August this year.

After ALDE-PSD alliance broke down, the PNL leader (Ludovic Orban--[no relationship](https://www.wsj.com/articles/leaders-of-neighboring-countries-share-a-name-confusion-ensues-11573832025) to Hungary's Viktor Orban though) was nominated by president Iohannis to lead the new government. In November they've managed to secure a confidence vote in Parliament. It's not clear not me what other parties support this PNL government and/or are a part of its coalition. Two news stories I've read in English; [DW](https://www.dw.com/en/romanias-new-government-wins-confidence-vote/a-51112839), [RFERL](https://www.rferl.org/a/romanian-prime-minister-designate-s-government-faces-confidence-vote/30251889.html) failed to fully explain who exactly supported the new PNL government and what role if any these other supporters have in the new PNL government.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe someone can provide some fuller answers, but some bits I've gathered are that:

It's officially a [minority PNL government](https://wiiw.ac.at/romania-new-president-and-new-government-amid-economic-slowdown-n-410.html).

> On 10 October, following a vote of no confidence, the governing coalition led by the Social Democratic Party (PSD) collapsed, when its junior partner, the Alliance of Liberals and Democrats (ALDE), called time on the collaboration. A minority National Liberal Party (PNL) government won a vote of confidence and was installed on 4 November. Then, barely three weeks later, on 24 November, the incumbent President Klaus Iohannis – also of the PNL – was duly elected for a further five-year term.

The new government supporters from outside PNL [appear to have been](https://www.politico.eu/article/romania-new-center-right-government-ludovic-orban/) (on one hand) defectors from the Social Democrat camp (which apparently has its own split, with former Social Democrat PM Victor Ponta having its own "Pro Romania" party now).

> Monday's vote in parliament was preceded by infighting in the center-left Pro Romania party of former PSD Prime Minister Victor Ponta. While Ponta said his party would boycott the vote, six of his 32 MPs voted in favor of the proposed government.
>
> The votes of rebel PSD and Pro Romania MPs, combined with support from independent ex-PSD and other MPs, ultimately proved crucial in giving Orban the required majority.

On [the other hand](https://wiiw.ac.at/romania-new-president-and-new-government-amid-economic-slowdown-n-410.html) it seems a third group (the USR-PLUS alliance) has been backing the PNL government:

> Initiatives could be forthcoming from two new parties that voted for the PNL government: the Save Romania Union (USR), formed in 2016 by civic activists, and the Freedom, Unity and Solidarity Party (PLUS), set up in October 2018 by Dacian Cioloș, currently president of the Renew Europe group in the European Parliament. The USR-PLUS alliance is the third-strongest political force in Romania; it runs on a clear anti-corruption ticket and enjoys urban support. In coalition with the PNL, it could form a strong pro-European government after the next election – provided it can win over at least part of the rural population, which has traditionally voted for the post-communist PSD.

Comment: Interesting to note that there's a difference between ALDE Europe and ALDE Romania. They used to be partners, but [they aren't anymore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alliance_of_Liberals_and_Democrats_(Romania)#History).

Answer (score 1):

This is a complementary answer since you have already provided some information about the current political context surrounding the Romanian's Government.

The Government is indeed [composed of PNL party members](https://ro.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guvernul_Ludovic_Orban) which theoretically makes it [a "dangerously" minority Government with only 96 MPs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_political_parties_in_Romania#Parties_represented_in_Parliament). This provides a simple answer to your question: only one party, PNL.

In practice, things are much more complicated than that since the Government must somehow rely on Parliamentary support. Indeed USR-Plus alliance supported PNL (along with "Pro Romania") to both bring down the previous government and install the new one, but they refused to take part in the forming of the government.

As some analysts argued, USR-Plus is in a strange situation: ideologically they are quite similar to PNL (pro-EU, pro-NATO, strongly against PSD), yet they are not part of the Government.

Also, to make things worse PNL + USR-Plus combined votes are not enough to ensure a majority in any of the Parliament's chambers. There will be tough times for the Government under these conditions since Parliament's support is very unstable.

On the other hand, the Government might force some things (assume responsibility in the Parliament) because there is a trick. If the Parliament brings down the government, another is proposed. Two rejected proposals means snap elections. This means an incomplete mandate for the MPs, which greatly affects their special pensions.